# How do I find missing data

Tags: sql

I have to find riskunits.descriptions that are missing on policies.

I can match riskunitid on policyid - but how do I find a policy that does not have a riskunit.description?  I am new to SQL

Comment: There seem to be missing details. Like the definition of your tables. And example data.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please start by telling us which DBMS you're using and then add your table definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your exact table structure, we'll have to make do with some pseudo code:

```
select * 
from policy p
where not exists (
  select *
  from riskunit r
  where r.policyid = p.policyid
)
```

This will find policies with no riskunit record. If you expect there will always be a riskunit record, but the description may be null or an empty string, go with this instead:

```
select * 
from policy p
  join riskunit r
    on r.policyid = p.policyid
where (r.description is null or r.description = '')
```